# "my network" function with sql subquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need a little help for one sql query;

here is my basic user database table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(40) NOT NULL, 
  `network` varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=27 ;
```

and here is my basic topics database table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `topics` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `body` text,
  `tags` varchar(256) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

What I'm trying to do is;
i.e. list all topics from users who joined "harvard" network

Comment: I'm not really good at sql subquery :/ 
all failed

Comment: I don't think you need a subquery for this.

Comment: Considering that you didn't explicitly make userid a foreign key, that you seem to have problems with the difference between a query and a subquery, and that you seem to have difficulty writing a relatively basic query, I would STRONGLY recommend that you find a general SQL tutorial and read over it (maybe even multiple times) before you do anything else with SQL.

Comment: To add to what @Jodaka said, you've got `user.id` using an int, and `topics.userid` as varchar - that's just going to cause problems down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a simple [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).  Join the tables on the userID (of those who are in `"harvard"`).

```
SELECT title,body
FROM topics, users
WHERE userid = users.id
AND network = 'harvard'
```

Or using the `JOIN` keyword:

```
SELECT title,body
FROM topics
JOIN users ON userid = users.id
WHERE network = 'harvard'
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, I think:

```
SELECT 
    title 
FROM 
    topics t
INNER JOIN
    users u ON t.userid=u.id 
WHERE 
    network='Harvard'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.title
FROM users u
INNER JOIN topics t ON u.id = t.userid
WHERE u.network = 'harvard'
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: You probably want `u.id = t.userid`.